# What is a reveal cleat (and why do I need it)?

Tags: cabinets, oven

I am DIY installing a wall oven.

Schematic calls out 3/4" reveal cleats.

I already have 3/4" lip in the cabinet.

Why would I use a reveal cleat?

[image]

```
EDIT: Update, I installed the oven (without the reveal cleats) with the dimensions given in the manual and it worked great.
```

Comment: I would think if your opening is 25 1/2" with your additional 3/4" on each side that no added cleats would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that the reveal cleat serves two functions.

1. It keeps the oven set in the middle of the opening  so that the reveal on the face frame of the cabinet is **equal on both sides**.

   *The reveal is the amount of the narrow strip of face frame that is visible between the trim of the oven and the edge of the face frame opposite it.*
2. It maintains an equal space between the side of the oven and the cabinet sides. ( inside the space of the cabinet )

Comment: 3. It allows you to insert the oven snugly against the cleats to establish the correct depth position with respect to the cabinet faces. (There may also be mounting screws that are installed into the cleats.)

Answer (score 1):

As it says, it's intended for flush installs where the oven door sits flush (inset) with the cabinet sides. The oven door closes against those recessed reveal cleats.